# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-02180: invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE'

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle18c, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am trying to create Oracle tablespace dynamically from C#.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("User Id=SYSTEM;Password=mw;Data Source=SampleDataSource"))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLESPACE MYTS DATAFILE 'D:\MYTS_001.DBF';";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws the following exception.

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-02180: invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE'
```

But when I execute the same statement in "SQL Plus" it works fine.

Comment: Hi, Can you try to remove the `;` from query and check?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `;` from query and check.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLESPACE MYTS DATAFILE 'D:\MYTS_001.DBF'";
```